# python primitive class constructor - int() can't convert non-string with explicit base -

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, constructor

I have read contructor theory in Python explaining that constructor inheritance is possible in Python. I have inherited int class into my class a. In principle, constructor in child class have highest priority. Why constructor of my child class does not evoke?

```
class a(int):
    def __init__(self,value1,value2):
       self.value1=value1
       self.value2=value2

obj1=a(2,2)
```

> TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base

Answer (score 3):

`int` is an immutable type in Python. That means that is does not use `__init__`, but `__new__`.

The difference between `__init__` and `__new__` is that `__init__` is an initializer, while `__new__` is a constructor. So, when `__init__` is called, your instance has already been created. In order to implement immutable objects, you want the ability to "cancel" creating a new object in some cases. For instance, when `int(1)` is performed, it would make little sense to create a new instance equal to `1`. In stead, the existing instance can simply be returned.

So, in theory, you could do something like this:

```
class a(int):
    def __new__(cls, value1, value2):
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
        return self
```

The error you are getting is because `a(2, 2)` calls `int.__new__` with two arguments: `2` and `2`. The two-argument form of `int.__new__` expects the first argument to be a `str` in a base specified by the second argument.

---

If you want to experiment with inheritance in Python, you might find it easier to use your own defined classes -- inheritance involving built-in classes can be tricky at times.

---

One additional detail I wanted to add: in my experience, you usually do not want to *replace* the initializer or constructor of your parent class. In stead, you probably want to *extend* it, like I did in my example above using the call to `super().__new__`. But then again, there might be valid use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that since `int` is immutable; the `__init__` cannot be changed, so `a(2, 2)` still ends up <s>looking</s> calling like `int(2, 2)`